# Работа с MySQL в Android'e

Tags: android, java, mysql

Здравствуйте, я начанающий программист под андройд, и по джаве собственно тоже. Пишу приложение для андройда и столкнулся со следующей задачей. Приложение должно брать информацию с сайта, а именно из базы MySQL. И тут ко мне в голову пришло два варианта решения этой задачи. Первый - это использовать стандартные классы джавы для работы с MySQL. Но будет ли приложение нормально работать на устройствах? В данном случает я так понимаю, что данные для доступа к базе (адрес, логин, пароль) будут храниться в самом приложении. Насколько это безопасно? Второй вариант решения - это создавать на сайте XML-страницу с данными из базы, а приложение уже будет парсить этот XML-файл. Какой вариант будет более оптимальным на ваш взгляд? Или может быть есть еще какие нибудь варианты?

Из этого всего выплывает очередной вопрос. Если я буду применять второй вариант, получается что приложение должно обращаться сначало не к XML-странице, а к php-скрипту которому приложение, сначало должно передать определенные параметры, а вот только потом получить сгенерированую налету XML-страницу и только потом ее считать. Не совсем понимаю как это реализовать, подскажите способы.

Ребята, подскажите возможно ли сделать так, что бы класс в джаве отправлял POST-запрос с параметрами к php-скрипту, который в свою очередь, возвращал бы в своем теле (например в echo) XML-разметку? И тут же этот ж класс обработал XML и выдал ее на экран. Со сторы php-проблем нет, опыт в нём у меня большой, скрипт я напишу без проблем, но вот со стороны джавы подскажите в какую сторону капать? =)

Comment: Мы реализовывали server-side, загоняли скрипт в Cron, он генерировал XML, ну а там просто красота, парсить можно любым ЯП. Сарказм, но при такой реализации программисту на Java (любой другой ЯП) и не нужно знать SQL / MySQL. =) Могу поделиться скриптом, он универсальный, реализован на PHP.

Comment: Буду очень признателен =) Потому как все сходится ко второму варианту

Comment: Решил вопрос методом GET с помощью статьи http://www.thaicreate.com/mobile/android-httpget-httppost.html =)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Первый вариант имеет один плюс - он гибче. Но это и его  недостаток. Если завтра захотите поменять одну таблицу, то нужно будет обновить программы на всех устройствах. А это может быть непросто. С другой стороны, если кто то  подглянет внутрь кода, то может вытянуть не только параметры подключения к базе, но и в  базу наведаться и там пошалить. А это уже очень печально.

Второй способ значительно лучше. Если структура базы поменяется - нужно просто переписать серверный скрипт. Более того, если запись в базу происходит не часто, а выборка значительно чаще, то кеширования файла с результатом сильно все разгрузит и ускорит. И это не преждевременная оптимизация. Это нормальное проектирование.

Но у второго способа есть один большой недостаток - xml. Мало того, что он сильно избыточный, так ещё распарсить его на клиенте не так и быстро (в одном из проектов, где я участвовал, был xml, на килобайт 30, который с ресурсов загружался и оттудова доставались  разные параметры. Отказавшись от него в пользу массива (а по факту - просто питоновский скрипт, который при компиляции генерировал жава код по xml), удалось сэкономить около полусекунды при старте приложения).

Мое предложения - используйте второй вариант, то с json (его парсер есть в поставке), а для некоторых данных может и простой текстовый формат. - нужно смотреть на конкретные данные. А ещё по верху можно прикрутить gzip сжатие.

Answer (score -1):

Не вдаваясь в архитектурные изыски сразу отмечу один важный момент, который упущен.

Дело в том, что в Android используется немного другая виртуальная машинка Dalvik VM - немного другая значит, что формат байткодов отличается от сановской JVM.

В данном случае это важно поскольку речь идет о JDBC драйвере MySQL, который может использовать нативные вызовы или прочие хитрости несовместимые с Dalvik VM. Так что в первую очередь надо убедиться в совместимости JDBC драйвера MySQL с Android'овской VM.